# Check whether an array of objects contain a given string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, search, underscore.js

I have an array of objects and need to find whether an array of objects contain a given value for any property? (It can be for any property).

E.g.:

```
[
    {product_name: "iphone 7s " , cost: "122"  , type: "product" },  
    {name: "John Snow " , email: "jon_snow@got.com"  , type: "contact"}, 
    {seller_name: "John Smith " , brand: "Xbrand"  , type: "seller"}
];
```

I need a function to return the last two objects in which value "John" exists.

Comment: Try iterating over the array, then iterate over the object while in ther first loop and search for the value !

Answer (score 3):

You could filter the array an check if a value of the object contains the wanted string.

```js
var data = [{ product_name: "I phone 7s ", cost: "122", type: "product" }, { name: "Joh Snow ", email: "jon_snow@got.com", type: "contact" }, { seller_name: "Joh Smith ", brand: "Xbrand", type: "seller" }],
    result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).some(s => s.includes('Joh')));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is loop through the array of objects, and check if the property value contains your text. Then you can add that to an array and take the last 2 from that array using [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

For example:

```js
var objects = [
    {product_name: "iphone 7s ", cost: "122", type: "product"},
    {name: "John Snow ", email: "jon_snow@got.com", type: "contact"},
    {seller_name: "John Smith ", brand: "Xbrand", type: "seller"}
];

function getObjectsContaining(coll, value) {
    var results = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        var obj = coll[i];
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property) && obj[property].indexOf(value) !== -1) {
                results.push(obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return results.slice(-2);
}

console.log(getObjectsContaining(objects, "John"));
```

Comment: Why results.slice(-2) ?